# 2006 ford explorer 4.6 v8 radiator replacement

Tags: ford, repair, radiator, explorer

I am installing a new radiator and so far everything has gone smoothly but i cannot get the feet to line up with the slots that they go into on the radiator bracket. It feels like there is a lip that is preventing them from just sliding right into place but I cannot figure it out. Has anybody else had this problem? Is my new radiator possibly slightly off? Its important they slide down in because the mounting bolts for  the radiator to the bracket don't line up until the feet slide in. New radiator looks exactly the same as the old as far as I can tell. If I cut these feet off will everything be okay?

Comment: “Looks exactly the same as the old” - so is that the metric or imperial eyball? Measure to be sure - that way you might find something is bent or misplaced.

Comment: Most of these have rubber bushings to isolate the radiator against vibration.  Make sure you don't have an extra one in the way.